# iOS grid like view with varying image sizes

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, grid

I've been looking for a while on stack overflow but haven't seen a question like this so here goes:

I need a grid like view as shown below that will populate each row with cells of varying size. In all the grid views I've seen all the cells are the same and it's been very difficult to customise to get what's shown below:

http://s7.postimage.org/7al1fs8jv/image.png

I'm running out of ideas and just wondering if anyone had any easier or better way of approaching this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manu ways to achieve this

1.By quartz 2D drawing

2.Customizing a view and using it load in a placeholder view by adding programatically by calculating rects

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to have upto 60 of these views so Quartz 2D is impractical? I dont understand the second method that well, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Quartz2D is the best way i think because if the data to show is already available and is meant to show only then Quartz2D will be fine.You will just have to implement a single view for drawing everything using Quartz2D

Comment: second method is the same that you mentioned .Using a set of view to show by calculating frame

Comment: Thanks, I want to show the day but also allow the user to click each image to initiate an event. Can I still do this with Quartz 2d?

Comment: In that case you have to use UIButton customized with Quartz2D by overriding the drawrect method